# What should I do if someone published my old reserarch result without mentioning my name?

Tags: plagiarism, research-misconduct

Recently, I realized someone, who was my friend in the past, published my research results related to an old project without mentioning my name. I'm wondering how he accessed to my results and why he published those results in a fake journal! By fake journal, I mean it's like someone buys a website and upload some pdfs and says I'm a publisher! Fortunately, it seems this guys recently got a faculty position in the US and I wanted to know how can I sue him? It's a clear example of research misconduct to publish the results of other people without mentioning even their name. I could prove my claim by giving the original raw data, which I'm pretty sure that he cannot provide them because I just stored them in a protected storage device. Could I directly contact the office of research compliance of the university that he works for?

Edited:

I realized it is more than one paper! He published two papers! in the same fake journal with my results...

Edited:

He admitted his fault and apologized... Also, he offered me three projects to work on and even a Postdoc position!!! (I'm still PhD student and even not defended my PhD proposal). I gave this matter up because he made the situation really emotional. I'm not sure that it is a correct thing to do or not but this question is kinda closed...

Comment: Is this actually a fake journal, or is it just his personal website. There is a significant difference.

Comment: It is ACTUALLY a fake journal and is not a personal website...!

Comment: This is the website of this fake journal: http://www.jbsjournal.org/

Comment: Sounds like you wouldn't want your name associated with any of it at all. It will not pass muster with your 'friend's university either, so I would just not bother with it at all...

Comment: @JonCuster You mean, I should give it up and let it go?

Comment: Perhaps. You should be clear with yourself what your issue is, and what you want to accomplish. Nobody else of any value will be fooled by a fake publication. What is it to you if the person makes a fool of themselves?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Unless your specialty is in femur visualization, it seems like this would be a pretty long road to chase just to get attribution for having created images found in a fake journal published in 2014. He could truly just get around this by putting your name in 8 point font at the end of the paper "Alone Programmer created the images using <some program>."

Comment: The research result is not fake! I mean I did that really but just I didn't get the time to publish them. If those results are published in a fake journal it does not mean the research results are also fake. Clearly, he toke some advantages out of it by himself. But let's say why I should give up my right to publish those results someday? I think it's not fair...

Comment: @Vladhagen Let's say right now I decided to publish this results in Elsevier? Can I do it? I have the raw data so I could generate other images as well to not be in a conflict with this fake article! But that sounds ridiculous because I'm trying to avoid my real results which belongs to me 100%. It's really hard to wrap my head around it... By the way right now his brother is saying this journal is not fake and " it has official ISSN from US Congress Library, official website, known editorial team and is indexed."

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Note that fake is not the same as "extremely low quality." As I have said, contact the man himself, then his department. If you are capable of writing a new paper on your own using your own images, publish your results how you see fit.

Comment: I already contacted him. Could I prove my claim by providing the raw data to at least remove this article from web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would first contact the individual who published your work. Perhaps he can provide insight into his actions.**

If he has a faculty position in the US, you could next contact his department to open a case with them. University administration may also be able to step in and arbitrate on the matter.

If the journal is reputable, they too would be a point of contact. Since I have no way of knowing what journal/"journal" this work was published in, it is difficult for me to gauge what contacting the journal would lead to.

Much of this will depend on providing evidence that you performed the work you say you did. This also greatly hinges on what exactly this person published that you think is yours. Did he publish written work verbatim from your own writings? Did he just publish a paper using an idea you had but never formalized? Did he publish data that you collected? Do you have any lab notebooks showing that you collected the data? Were you paid to do research for this person? Is he publishing a paper using data that you collected, but that he cleaned and analysed?

One note on pursuing civil litigation on this matter: Unless you can show loss of money, opportunity, or standing due to this person's actions, you are extremely unlikely to get a definitive decision awarding you some sort of remuneration for your work. This is not how civil suits work. This is an academic matter and the courts are likely not going to hear the case. (Unless you go to some sort of TV 'Judge Judy' court). *If you have an actual published piece of work that is copyrighted, civil action could be a move of last resort.* Otherwise, civil action is very unlikely to result in anything.

Comment: The journal is completely fake and just invented by him and his brother! By sue, my purpose is to remove this fake article from web and all of its records. Also he used the data that I collected without mentioning my name as author. I have all the raw data which I'm pretty sure that he cannot provide them because I just stored them in a protected storage device.

Comment: By using my data, my purpose is that he used some pictures which I created for visualization from raw data to show him sometimes ago directly in this accused paper without doing anything new. He could not do anything new because he didn't have the raw data.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer So he used some images you created? Was the focus of the paper visualization? For all we know, you created those images for him, he forgot who created the images (several years having passed), and then he used them in a pre-print he put on his personal website. Were these images you created done on your own time? Did he pay you to do this research?

Comment: I did not created those images for him! This paper is written solely based on my images without any new result. No it was not like a pay job or anything like that. Me and him had a friendship in our department some years ago when he was PhD student and I was a undergraduate. I did some research independently in our department with a software which I learned at that time by attending some sort of classes. Sometime I just showed my results to him to know his opinion. But I realized that he stole my images which I don't know how! But he does not have raw data.

Comment: Right now, I'm a PhD student in the US and also he is in the US (such a coincidence!), but I don't know, is it possible to open any case against him in his university because this research is not done in the US originally.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Plagiarism is plagiarism, regardless of what country the research was originally performed in. First contact him, then his department.

Comment: I already contacted his brother, who works in the same university as him, because even in his webpage in the university, there is no contact information to contact this guy! It may sound ridiculous but I'm suspicious that maybe this university is also faked by him and his brother! I'm waiting to see what he would say!

Comment: Rowan University is a real university in the United States (New Jersey).